# Make bootsrap4.x nav pills with toggle switch instead of button or link make it switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the boostrap nav tab pill but instead of using nav pills button I want to make it a toggle switch

So far my code include the button/pills for toggling the content but I'm not able to make it a switch

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

home
  profile
  contact

Instead of some pills button make it a switch

Comment: Please post the code which have tried using switch.

Comment: @SaiManoj I've edited my post with switch code that u asked for

Comment: Please check the below snippet and let me know if it works out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by `jQuery toggle` to show `this` value and hide the siblings by using `siblings("class").hide()`
Below is the working snippet for the same

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    $("." + inputValue).toggle().siblings(".box").hide()
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff0000;
  display: none
}

.green {
  background: #228B22;
  display: none
}

.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
  display: block;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue" checked>
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
  <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
  <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
</div>

<div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
```

Comment: I want to have three state toogle switch  ---- https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH2MN.png ---- like this image but with text'=. Also by default first one should be selected with its content to be shown

Comment: What do you mean by three state toggle switch? As per your question you need switches to display the content of selected switch. Please edit your question if that's not the case

Comment: ur answer is exactly what i needed really appreciate your response but i need some changes in the switches. I want something like this ------------------> https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH2MN.png . But with text . Also by defualt first switch state should be selected

Comment: @AISHWERYASINGH i have made the changes for defualt first switch state should be selected. You need to change the css to do that kind of check box. I hope I have answered the question. Please accept my answer if this helped you

Comment: what have you done exactly in order to make the blue box show by default

Comment: @AISHWERYASINGH in css you can show that by using `display:block`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/84m6z23j/6/   i was able to implement what i wanted but its not exactly working ....any solution ??